# Find/parse server-side <?abc?>-like tags in html document

Tags: c#, html, regex

I guess I need some regex help. I want to find all tags like `<?abc?>` so that I can replace it with whatever the results are for the code ran inside. I just need help regexing the tag/code string, not parsing the code inside :p.

`<b><?abc print 'test' ?></b>` would result in `<b>test</b>`

Edit:  Not specifically but in general, matching `(<?[chars] (code group) ?>)`

Comment: Do you mean that the it will always have a print 'something' and you will want to replace the whole <?abc print 'something' ?> with 'something'?

Comment: I am no C# expert, but the concept should work like this. Find <?abc print ' using some sort of search/find function. Then, store that position. From there, find the next ' which occurs (to allow for escaping, find the next ' character without a \ before it [\' = escaping]). Or find ' ?>. From there, use a substring function from position of the first for the length between position and position 2 and your result will be what's found in the "print ' '" tags.

Comment: I want my own <?php?> type of tag that I can find and also group the code contents into. `(<?php(code group)?>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will build up a new copy of the string `source`, replacing `<?abc code?>` with the result of `process(code)`

```
Regex abcTagRegex = new Regex(@"\<\?abc(?<code>.*?)\?>");

StringBuilder newSource = new StringBuilder();
int curPos = 0;

foreach (Match abcTagMatch in abcTagRegex.Matches(source)) {
    string code = abcTagMatch.Groups["code"].Value;
    string result = process(code);

    newSource.Append(source.Substring(curPos, abcTagMatch.Index));
    newSource.Append(result);
    curPos = abcTagMatch.Index + abcTagMatch.Length;
}

newSource.Append(source.Substring(curPos));
source = newSource.ToString();
```

---

N.B. I've not been able to test this code, so some of the functions may be slightly the wrong name, or there may be some off-by-one errors.

Comment: I wouldn't normally advocate using `.*?`, but all the alternatives to matching 'everything up to this series of characters' I could think of were too convoluted and messy.

Comment: *I want EVERYTHING! But very little of it!* hehe

Comment: If I just did a output of the code group it seems `<?abc echo '?>'; ?>` results in `echo ''; ?>`. You also missed a paren on the 2nd to last line. It's a good start though and I think I know enough to fix that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var new Regex(@"<\?(\w+) (\w+) (.+?)\?>")
```

This will take this source

```
<b><?abc print 'test' ?></b>
```

and break it up like this:

```
Value: <?abc print 'test' ?>

    SubMatch: abc
    SubMatch: print
    SubMatch: 'test'
```

These can then be sent to a method that can handle it differently depending on what the parts are.

If you need more advanced syntax handling you need to go beyond regex I believe.

I designed a template engine using [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) but thats way more complex  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
exp = new Regex(@"<\?abc print'(.+)' \?>");
str = exp.Replace(str, "$1")
```

Something like this should do the trick.  Change the regexes how you see fit